# c pointer explanation wanted

Tags: c, pointers

I am newbiew regarding pointer, Can anybody explain me the dissimilarity of output in the following code ? In the following code i am assigning some value to a 3d pointer. I printed them after assignment. Then again printed them in different block. How come the output be different ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define row 5
#define rw 3
#define col 10

char ***ptr,sh[10];
int i,j,k;

int main()
{
    ptr=(char *)malloc(row*sizeof(char *));

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        *(ptr+i)=(char *)malloc(rw*sizeof(char *));
        printf("\t:\n");

        for(j=0;j<rw;j++)
        {
            *(*(ptr+i)+j)=(char *)malloc(col*sizeof(char *));

            if(i==0 && j==0)
            {       
                //  *(*(ptr+row)+rw)="kabul";
                **ptr="zapac";
            }
            else
            {
                sh[0]=i+48;
                sh[1]=',';
                sh[2]=j+48;
                sh[3]='\0';
                *(*(ptr+i)+j)=sh;
            }

            printf("\t%d%d = %s\n",i,j,ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<rw;j++)
        {
            printf("\t%d%d %s\n",i,j,ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
    :
    00 = zapac
    01 = 0,1
    02 = 0,2

    :
    10 = 1,0
    11 = 1,1
    12 = 1,2

    :
    20 = 2,0
    21 = 2,1
    22 = 2,2

    :
    30 = 3,0
    31 = 3,1
    32 = 3,2

    :
    40 = 4,0
    41 = 4,1
    42 = 4,2
```

My question is, why is the following output disagree with the above ?

```
    00 zapac
    01 4,2
    02 4,2

    10 4,2
    11 4,2
    12 4,2

    20 4,2
    21 4,2
    22 4,2

    30 4,2
    31 4,2
    32 4,2

    40 4,2
    41 4,2
    42 4,2
```

Comment: `ptr` is not a pointer to a pointer but pointer to a pointer pointing to another pointer. `char ***ptr; ptr=(char *)malloc(row*sizeof(char *));` Are u sure that this statement passed with out any compilation error ?

Comment: Then how should I assign something like, ptr[0][0]="mahesh" ptr[0][1]="maverick" ptr[1][0]="pqrst" with pointer representation ?

Comment: yes it is... and i just copied the output

Comment: [warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type](http://ideone.com/Ah21a) at Ideone

Comment: @Mahesh, I am really a newbie regarding pointer. I had a "suspicious pointer conversion" warning. though no error was shown. can you then tell me how should i assign memory and by the process have my expected output ?

Comment: in C it's allowed to do totally crazy things. that's why it's *just* a warning.

Comment: @yi_H,I am really a newbie regarding pointer. I had a "suspicious pointer conversion" warning. though no error was shown. can you then tell me how should i assign memory and by the process have my expected output

Comment: we are really glad that you can copy-paste, thanks for the demo.

Comment: @yi_H: I think you may tell me, that is wrong with my code... what is wrong ?

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc()`.

Comment: You could try with a two dimensional array first to make things easier. This code is hard to read.

Comment: @Mahesh: The argument to `malloc()` is just an integer expression, converted to `size_t`; there's nothing there for the compiler to complain about.  The safest way to initialize `ptr` is `ptr = malloc(row * sizeof *ptr);`.

Comment: @pithikos i m trying it in the harder way with an intention to dig deep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting the output you are is that your `*(*(ptr+i)+j) = sh` is setting all of the `char *`s (except the first, which you have treated specially) to the same value, which is the address of the array data in `sh`.  There's only one copy of `sh`, one copy of its array data; all your `char *`s point to that single copy.  When you print out the values later, you're just printing this same copy of the data over and over again via different pointers to it -- so you get whatever you put in `sh` the last time you modified it rather than what was in it when you set the pointer.

You probably expected each `char *` to get a new copy of the array instead of just being pointed at `sh`, but if that's what you want you have to copy the data yourself.

So... if you replace this line:

```
*(*(ptr+i)+j)=sh;
```

with something like:

```
*(*(ptr+i)+j)=malloc(sizeof(sh));
strcpy( *(*(ptr+i)+j), sh );
```

or

```
ptr[i][j] = calloc(1,sizeof(sh));
strcpy( ptr[i][j], sh );
```

you'll get what you expected, because each `char *` will point at a new copy of the string that was in `sh` at the time of the copy.  You'll need to remember to free them later, along with everything else you've `malloc()`ed, though.

Most of your `malloc()` lines are incorrect as well, but since `char *`, `char **`, and `char ***` are probably all the same size on your system, it works anyway.

```
ptr=(char *)malloc(row*sizeof(char *));
```

should be

```
ptr = (char ***)malloc(row*sizeof(char **));
```

since you're allocating an array of `char **` (pointer to pointer to `char`), which is accessed through a `char ***` (pointer to *pointer to pointer to `char`*).  Likewise:

```
*(ptr+i)=(char *)malloc(rw*sizeof(char *));
```

should be

```
*(ptr+i)=(char **)malloc(rw*sizeof(char *));
```

or

```
ptr[i] = (char **)malloc(rw * sizeof(char *));
```

to allocate an array of `char *` (pointer to `char`) accessed via a `char **` (pointer to *pointer to `char`*).

The casts in front of your `malloc()` calls are actually optional -- `malloc()`'s `void *` result would be converted to whatever pointer type you assigned it to anyway.  In this case, though, having the casts there should have made your compiler warn you that you had the types wrong.

Comment: @Dimitri  thanks, dmitri... i aint still good enough to vote you up.... i used the cast so that it works on every compiler..... it really helped...:)

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt: Without the cast, it will work on every C compiler -- at least if you remember the `#include <stdlib.h>` so the compiler knows what `malloc()` looks like.

Comment: @Keith, I have found that without cast and with stdlib Dev-C++ gives compiler error : invalid conversion

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt: Then Dev-C++ isn't a C compiler.  Judging by the name, I'd say it's a C++ compiler.  Don't make the mistake of thinking that C and C++ aren't two different languages.  And if you want to program in C, you need to use a C compiler (there may be a way to tell Dev-C++ to act as one).

Answer (score 0):

Because **sh[10]** is defined globally and while the first loop you are printing the current values of this array - the contents of this array are not preserved - changing on each iteration. For the second loop you are printing the last value written during the first loop (i.e. on the last iteration).

You'd better allocate on each iteration of the first loop:

```
       for(j=0;j<rw;j++)
       {
            *(*(ptr+i)+j)=(char *)malloc(col*sizeof(char *));
            char* psh = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
            if(i==0 && j==0)
            {       
               strcpy(psh, "zapac");
            }
            else
            {
                psh[0]=i+48;
                psh[1]=',';
                psh[2]=j+48;
                psh[3]='\0';
                *(*(ptr+i)+j)=psh;
            }
```

PS be aware of hard-coded 10-char size, possibly you need additional checks/assertions.

Comment: if sh[10] is assigned locally... i get same answer. btw, in the first block after i did assign sh values to ptr isn't the value of sh becomes irrelevant ? i.e. ptr are supposed to have all the data regardless of the condition of sh. isn't it ?

Comment: No matter how it's assigned, the point is that *(*(ptr+i)+j) - all the same - they point to the same location which is sh[10]. You have to have different sh[10] per each i,j, i.e. i*j instances in memory

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitri is right about what caused the symptom you're seeing, but there are other problems in your code, some serious, some less so.

Here's a modified version of your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW 5
#define RW 3
#define COL 10

int main(void)
{
    char ***ptr;
    char sh[10];
    ptr = malloc(ROW * sizeof *ptr);

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = malloc(RW * sizeof *(ptr[i]));
        printf("\t:\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < RW; j++)
        {
            ptr[i][j] = malloc(COL * sizeof *(ptr[i][j]));

            if (i==0 && j==0)
            {       
                //  *(*(ptr+ROW)+RW) = "kabul";
                ptr[i][j] = "zapac";
            }
            else
            {
                sh[0] = '0' + i;
                sh[1] = ',';
                sh[2] = '0' + j;
                sh[3] = '\0';
                // ptr[i][j] = sh;
                strcpy(ptr[i][j], sh);

            }

            // printf("\t%d%d = %s\n", i, j, ptr[i][j]);
            printf("\tptr[%d][%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, j, ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < RW; j++)
        {
            // printf("\t%d%d %s\n", i, j, ptr[i][j]);
            printf("\tptr[%d][%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, j, ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The changes I've made are:

1. Add `#include <stdlib.h>` to get the declaration of `malloc()`.  This is not optional (though the compiler might let you get away with omitting it).  In the absence of the `#include <stdlib.h>` a pre-C99 compiler will assume that `malloc()` returns an `int`; this results in undefined behavior.  That means that arbitrarily bad things can happen -- or it might happen to work on some systems.
2. Follow the usual convention of using all-caps names for macros.
3. Add some whitespace (I find that it makes the code more legible, particularly having a space after each comma and around most operators).
4. Make variables local rather than global.
5. Declare loop control variables in their respective loops.  This is a C99-specific feature, but your compiler probably supports it.  (For gcc, use `gcc -std=c99`.)
6. Fix the `malloc()` calls to compute the size from the size of what the pointer points to.
7. Use the indexing operator rather than explicit pointer arithmetic.  In general, `x[y]` means `*(x+y)`, so, for example, `*(*(ptr+i)+j)` can be written simply as `ptr[i][j]`.
8. Use `strcpy()` to copy the string stored in `sh` into `the string pointed to by`ptr[i][j]`, rather than just copying the pointer.  (This fixes the problem that Dmitri already found; you should probably accept his answer, since he mentioned it first.)
9. Modify the output produced by the `printf` calls so it's easier to see what's going on.

Comment: I intentionally used *(*(ptr+i)+j) instead of ptr[i][j] just to have it mind how it actually works... usually I use the usual. alongside dimitris answer, ur answer is handy too. thanks a lot